# Complex function parameter from C# to F#

Tags: f#

I have the next code (a parameter of a method) in C#:

```
Func<Func<string, Stream>, Action<string, string>, T> save
```

But I don't know if in F# is

```
save: ((string -> Stream) -> (string -> string -> unit)) -> 'T
```

or

```
save: (string -> Stream) -> (string -> string -> unit) -> 'T
```

Comment: If you know two possible options, why not try each and see which one works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say that `string -> Stream` is `'a` and `string -> string -> unit` is `'b` and `'T` is `'c`.

Now that we've removed the higher order functions this is simpler to think about and the question boils down to this: What's the difference between the following type signatures?

```
('a -> 'b) -> 'c
 'a -> 'b  -> 'c
```

The first type is a function that takes a function from `'a` to `'b` as its only argument. The second one is a function that takes an `'a` as its first argument and a `'b` as its second argument. The second one is compatible with the C# type signature `Func<A, B, C>`.